# Marvell C++ compiler (for Windows CE) for building Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I was able to build Qt 4.5 for Windows CE (ARM4VI) using MS VisualC++ compiler.
Now, I am trying to compile Qt 4.5 for Windows CE 5.0 using Marvel C++ compiler v 2.2 (former Intel C++ compiler for XScale architecture) for achieving some performance benefit. It seems, that this compiler not officially supported for building Qt by trolltech (no appropriate mkspec in mkspec's folder of Qt folder).
 So, my questions:

- Is it worth to trying build Qt by this compiler for achieving performance enhancement ?

  Is there any way for building Qt using Marvell C++ compiler (by creating my own mkspec or something like that)?

Comment: Is Qt's performance actually a *problem*?

Comment: I have slow Qt working when loading application, when switching between dialogs, when switching tabs in tabwidget etc. In this moments our app does nothing expensive in background... (We have pretty outdated hardware platform, but MFC shows very good results in smoothness comparing to Qt)

Answer (score 0):

Create your own mkspecs based on wince mkspecs. Perhaps, you need WinCE SDK (created from BSP) of your specific platform.